# How to bind the records into DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagridview, datatable

Winforms Application

Code:

```
        var proxy = new ServiceNow_incident
        {
            Url = "https://instance.service-now.com/change_request.do?SOAP",
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password")
        };

        var objRecord = new getRecords
        {
            number = "CH1****234"
        };

        var recordsResults = proxy.getRecords(objRecord);

        //grdGetRecords is DataGridView.
```

`getRecords` is of type [getRecordsResponseGetRecordsResult[]](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Microsoft_.NET_Web_Services_Client_Examples#getRecords). I want to bind the `recordsResults` into `grdGetRecords` - *DataGridView Control* with *headers*.

Comment: Parse this to some IEnumerable like ObservableCollection, List or something and then bind it to Your DataGrid

Comment: `grdGetRecords.DataSource = recordsResults;`

Comment: This may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx - I suspect you may need to convert your recordsResults into something else though to pass it to the BindingSource. I'd try it first as is and if it doesn't work then into a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

first make the records result a public property:

```
public getRecordsResponseGetRecordsResult[] RecordsResults { get; set; }
```

Seconds bind in the xaml page throught a Binding in the ItemsSource:

```
<DataGridView ItemsSource="{Binding RecordsResults}" />
```

If you want dynamic update from the source or the view then be sure to put the Binding into TwoWay and make the property an ObservableCollection.

Hope it help!

Comment: It is the `winforms application`.

Answer (score 0):

I set the `recordsResults` to the `DataSource` property of `grdGetRecords`.

Code:

```
var recordsResults = proxy.getRecords(objRecord);
grdGetRecords.DataSource = recordsResults; // Code added for data binding
```

Now, the *record* has been binded to the `DataGridView` control.